# Creating a local workspace for development/testing

Tags: mount, symlink, fuse

I want to be able to `mount`, say /home/$USER/workspace to /usr/local/workspace.
Right now I'm using the python package [pyfilesystem](http://code.google.com/p/pyfilesystem/) which uses `fuse` to do that. My problem is, that inside that mount I am not able to create `symlinks`. I don't even need symlinks going outside the mount, but even a symlink that normally is created for a shared library during compilation, will not be created inside the mount.

So I'm either looking for a totally different approach, or a tool (preferably written in `Python`) that does exactly what `pyfilesystem` is doing and supports the creation of symlinks.

Further constraints:

- Using a simple symlink instead of a mount does not work for me as the mounted directory will actually be inside a `chroot`.
- Mounting must not require root privileges.
- Changing `fstab` is not an option.
- Thus using `mount bind` is not an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching some more I stumbled upon [proot](http://proot.me/) which combines `chroot`  with the ability to `mount` any directory into the new `root`. It supports any file operation inside its `chroot`, yes even `symlinks`, that will happily work even after `proot` unmounted the directory.
It doesn't need `root` privileges and made my complicated setup of `schroot` + `pyfilesystem` unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but such system-wide changes do require some form of root involvement, if just for sanity's sake. Perhaps the nearest to what you want is to create a virtual machine and play in it, or something like Fedora's [mock](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Projects/Mock), the mechanism used to create a chroot populated with the required tools to build a package. Probably other distributions have something similar. The whole namespace development in Linux promises help here, there is a series in [LWN](http://lwn.net) running now ([part 1](http://lwn.net/Articles/531114/), [part 2](http://lwn.net/Articles/531381/), [part3](https://lwn.net/Articles/531419/), [part 4](http://lwn.net/Articles/532748/); part 5 is still subscriber-only). But namespace setup will still be a root responsibility.

Comment: As I wrote it already works. I've been using this setup for quite some time. Using schroot and pyfilesystem I don't need root privileges anywhere. The only thing that does not work is the mentioned symlink part. Should I maybe rephrase my question to include something about symlinks?

Comment: Thanks for the edit of the question but I think that this is not specific enough. The fact that I'm using this setup for development/compiling has nothing to do with the problem.

Comment: @OrimKurowe, I don't see much other use of such a functionality, that's why I propose labelling the question that way.

Comment: I do have use for that functionality and I'm hoping I'm not the only one...

Comment: As I say, system-wide changes should _not_ be in the hands of any random user who happens to be using the machine. To use the obligatory car analogy: sure, it would often come handy if I could just hop into the next car and drive off with it, but I suspect the owner won't be too happy about it.

Comment: How is that a system-wide change? Just because a directory is mounted somewhere else? That's what fuse is there for. Filesystem in __user__ space. The bits about the chroots are not important to the question. I just wanted to give some context, which might have been a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You can setup a full build/testing environment as a normal user by combining tools like [fakechroot](https://github.com/fakechroot/fakechroot/wiki), [fakeroot](http://fakeroot.alioth.debian.org/) and [cowdancer](http://www.netfort.gr.jp/~dancer/software/cowdancer.html).